# how to normalize always changing data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, batch-normalization

I am training a model using tensorflow and i am using stock price information.  the thing i am not sure about is that i query for one stocks data and then fit with my test and validation sets using StandardScaler() but then for the next stock the data might be a different fit so im not sure how i should be addressing normalization in this issue if the training, test sequences are always going to have different scales all of the time

```
 data, indexes, retdat = get_data(ticker)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    train_data = data
    env = StockTradingEnv(train_data, initial_investment)
    testx, testy = [], []
    for e in range(env.n_step):
        x, y = env._get_obs(e)
        testx.append(x)
        testy.append(y)


    scaler.fit(testx)
    testx = scaler.transform(testx)
    tesx, valx = splitter(testx)
    tesy, valy = splitter(testy)
```

so this code above is kind of in a loop calling different stock tickers.  Im just not sure about the use of standard scaler here and if i should save it to a file or if using a new scaler every time is right or what.

any more information i can provide thank you for your time

Comment: that StandardScaler is using standard deviation instead of min&max, i know the mean and the value of standard deviation is changing, but maybe u can get a large large amount of data to calculate mean and standard deviation just once

Comment: maybe like a really high priced stock and a really low priced stock

Comment: Something I've employed successfully in modeling stock data is to normalize each instance to [-1, 1]. So say you have a time series of 10,000 days and you break those up in to chunks of 128 and try to predict the next 16 days. Regardless of the ticker, I normalize each 128 training instance to [-1, 1] and keep the min and max as a feature so I can transform back at test time. Or better stated, I create chunks, then normalize, not normalize and then create chunks.

Comment: @gobrewers14 is there a scaler that does that [-1,1] or do i have to manually do it?

Comment: sounds like the MinMaxScaler() but when i use it on the data, it jut doesnt seem like its right

Comment: like the minmaxscaler it seems like it turns alot of the values to 0, and 1

Comment: If it did it right, you wouldn't have time to ask questions on stack overflow. You would be too busy dealing with the consequence of unlimited wealth.

Comment: Try using [Tensorflow transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/transform/census) to preprocess the data.